# XLPagerTabStrip: add space between ButtonBarView and NavigationBar iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, xlpagertabstrip

I'm using [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) in a swift 3 application.

This is my storyboard:

[image]
[image]

I added CollectionView to VC in Interface Builder, and set its class to "ButtonBarView"

I added top space contrains to ButtonBarView to have space between it and navigationBar but it keep always 0 space

Comment: did you link your buttonBarView to outlet?

Comment: No, cause when i did that, it disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make your buttonBarView linked to your `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController` `buttonBarView`

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, i linked buttonBarView and also containerView to ScrollView and it work now :)

Comment: @OuSS Iam glad to help, happy coding and best regards

Comment: @ReinierMelian can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738384/how-to-use-xlpagertabstrip-library-by-hiding-navigation-bar